# How to fix the environment error while downloading python?

Tags: python

I got the error below while downloading the sklearn module using Python version 3.8.6.

```
ERROR: Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [WinError 5] Access is denied: 'C:\\Users\\LENOVO\\AppData\\Local\\Packages\\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\\LocalCache\\local-packages\\Python38\\site-packages\\sklearn\\.libs\\vcomp140.dll'
```

Comment: Contact IT, try open cmd with run as Admin,and try installing

Comment: Try with the --user option